# WSDL not available while running from threads JAVA

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, soapui

I am calling a soap web service in a thread. but it is giving below exception.
But when I run that webservice from SoapUI, it is working. Please help me with this.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (default task-29) RESTEASY002010: Failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8082/WISE/JCBRollOffService?wsdl
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.ClassNode.match(ClassNode.java:75) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:48) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:445) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:257) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:194) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:221) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51) [resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.16.Final-redhat-1.jar:3.0.16.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:285) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:264) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:175) [undertow-servlet-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:792) [undertow-core-1.3.21.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.3.21.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_151]
```

Comment: Show the code you are using to call the webservice.

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to access soap with rest.